# Помогите с фильтром

Tags: angular

У меня есть компонент в котором я перебираю из файла сотрудников, сотрудники 
выводятся, пытаюсь добавить фильтр для выбора отдельного сотрудника и что-то  идёт не так((.

Вот  файл - locale.html:

```
<div class="button__home"><a class="btn__home"[routerLink]="[ '/dashboard' ]" 
routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="dashboard" >На головну</a></div>

<!-- <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl"> -->

<ul>

<p>Фільтр по співробітникам</p>

<li ng-repeat="users | filter : {'sotrudnik': sotrudnik: true">
<p><input type="text" ng-model="test">

</ul>

<!-- </div> -->


<json-table
[dataSource]="users"
[headers]="customHeaders"                                 
[update]="true"
(deleteRow)="deleteByIdS($event)"
(updateRow)="updateChanges($event)">
</json-table>
```

Вот locale.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JSONTableModule } from 'angular-json-table'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { FilterInputDirective } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { map } from '@progress/kendo-data-query/dist/npm/transducers';

@Component({
selector: 'app-locale',
templateUrl: './locale.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./locale.component.scss']
})


export class LocaleComponent  implements OnInit  {
users : any;


customHeaders: any = {
thead: ['Сотрудник','Апаратура','Сообщение','Дата'], // the Column Name in 
table head.
displayed: ['sotrudnik','apparatura','soobshchenie','data'] // the data it 
should populate in table.
};

constructor(private httpclient : HttpClient )
{
new FilterInputDirective(this.users)
map((response:Response) => <any>response.json().timecontrolemployee)
while (this.users) {

}(data => console.log(data))

}

ngOnInit(): void {

this.httpclient.get<any> 
('https://bridge.buddyweb.fr/api/timecontrolemployee/timecontrolemployee')       
.subscribe(res => {this.users = res;});
alert(this.users[1].sotrudnik);

}
deleteByIdS(ids)
}

updateChanges(row){}

}
```

Помогите плиз ))

Comment: Как-то странно, эти строки от angularJs `<li ng-repeat="users | filter : {'sotrudnik': sotrudnik: true">
<p><input type="text" ng-model="test">`, а контроллер написан на Angular, у вас точно гибрид приложений AngualrJs и Angular2+?

Comment: Это я просто пробую что может работать и разный фильтр применяю. Изючаю всего 2-й месяц. Поэтому и обратился сюда за помошью.